# Como atualizo uma linha do datatable com jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Tenho o seguinte código funcionando para adicionar uma linha na tabela dinamicamente

```
var NovaLinha = [usuario,email,senha,ativo,acao];
NovaLinha.id = retorno;
$('#tabela').DataTable().row.add(NovaLinha).draw();
```

agora quero alterar ela também com jquery e o código abaixo não está funcionando. O que estou fazendo de errado abaixo?

```
var NovaLinha = [usuario,email,senha,ativo,acao];
$('#tabela').DataTable().row('#'+id).data(NovaLinha).draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o método [`fnUpdate`](http://datatables.net/api) para isso.

> Atualiza uma célula ou linha da tabela - este método irá aceitar um
>   valor único para atualizar a célula, um array de valores com um
>   elemento para cada coluna ou um objeto no mesmo formato que a fonte de
>   dados original.

Exemplo:

```
var tbl = $('#tabela').dataTable({ ... })
tbl.fnUpdate(['Baz', 'Baz@bar.com', 'pass', 'no'], 1);
```

Demonstração no <kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ou3nv9wg/)</kbd>